# Windows Phone: random number generation from list throws "Argument Out Of Range Exception"

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, random, parameters

This is my scenario: in order to make a random assignation of DISTINCT random numbers within a range, I create a list from 0 to 9, and an array of Buttons, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers2BeDrawn; i++)
{
    draft.Add(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < numbers2BeDrawn; i++)
{
    num = rnd.Next(draft.Count());
    myNumber = "" + i;

    if (myNumber.Length < 2) myNumber = "0" + myNumber;

    buttonList[draft[num]].Content = myNumber;
    draft.RemoveAt(num);
 }
```

That way, I make sure every button has a number from 0 to 9 without duplication. So far so good...

Now, each time I press a button, starting from 0 and going up to 9, I want it to dissapear, get its number taken away from the draft list and the rest shuffled and distributed again among the remaining active buttons, code being:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //write a common procedure for all buttons 
        var myButton = sender as Button;
        if(myButton != null) 
        {
            var buttonTag = myButton.Content;
            btnText = buttonTag.ToString();
        }

        myNum = "" + currentNum;

    if (myNum.Length < 2) myNum = "0" + myNum;
        if (myNum.Equals(btnText))
        {
            myButton.Opacity = 0;
            currentNum++;

            DrawNumbers();
        }
}

private void DrawNumbers()
{
        //clear the list and create it again with the numbers left
        draft.Clear();

        for (int i = numbers2BeDrawn; i > currentNum; i--)
        {
            draft.Add(i - 1);
        }

        //now, distribute them among the VISIBLE BUTTONS ONLY

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers2BeDrawn; i++)
        {
            if (buttonList[i].Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                num = rnd.Next(draft.Count());
                myNumber = "" + draft[num];
                if (myNumber.Length < 2) myNumber = "0" + myNumber;
                buttonList[i].Content = myNumber;
                draft.RemoveAt(num);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it throws an "Argument Out Of Range Exception" when I click on any button. It will work if I do:

```
        //substitution on the 'for' statement
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (buttonList[i].Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                num = rnd.Next(draft.Count());
                myNumber = "" + draft[num];
                if (myNumber.Length < 2) myNumber = "0" + myNumber;
                buttonList[i].Content = myNumber;
                draft.RemoveAt(num);
            }
        }
```

This will 'work' (will shuffle, but only on the first 5 buttons and not all of them as needed) for as long as I click any button up to '04' in this case (will throw exception on clicking '05'); if I change it for any other number, it will 'work' until reaching the stated limit.

Any ideas? I've tried the same code under Android and works perfectly by tweaking some stuff (nothing but *Size()* instead of *Count()*, *Remove* instead of *RemoveAt*, etc.; besides that, code remains completely the same). I've tried debugging and stopping in every single line, it provides that error at line

```
myNumber = "" + draft[num];

//error: ArgumentOutOfRangeException not found. parameter name: index
```

but I can't figure it out and, the more I check it out, the weirder I'm getting.

Thanks in advance, hope you have all the needed stuff (please tell me otherwise).

Mario.

Comment: as far I understand you want to shuffle your buttons. Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle it fits better

Comment: Thanks Lukas. The Fisher-Yates approach is what I'm trying to emulate, however, shuffling wasn't really the problem, it was rather an error thrown by a wrong IF statement check, as explained below. It's been solved, thanks again for your input and the interesting reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `myNumber = "" + draft[i];` instead? Which should also turn your `draft.RemoveAt(num);` into `draft.RemoveAt(i);`

Edit:

I am running this code on my machine and it finishes without error. In the end, draft contains no elements. Tell me how is it different than your scenario?

```
        Collection<int> draft = new Collection<int>();
        int numbers2BeDrawn = 100; int num; string myNumber; Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers2BeDrawn; i++)
        {
            draft.Add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers2BeDrawn; i++)
        {
            num = rnd.Next(draft.Count());
            myNumber = "" + i;

            if (myNumber.Length < 2) myNumber = "0" + myNumber;

            //buttonList[draft[num]].Content = myNumber;
            draft.RemoveAt(num);
        }
```

Edit2: Use `myButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;` instead `myButton.Opacity = 0;`

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint at the line it crashes? What are the values for i, num, draft.Count()?
You can use the Intermediate Window (Ctrl+Alt+I) to check this or just inspect with mosueover.

Comment: In this case: 
i = 0
num = 82
draft.count = 99

if I keep going till i = 99 (hitting F11), then it all crashes as draft.count is equal to 0 then...

Comment: So you can't generate a random number number between 0 and 0. Does that mean your for statement should be `(for i = 0; i < 98; i++)` ?
It appears that the crash occurs on the last iteration of `i`, which means you should just stop one step before it. In your example above, you are only doing 5 iterations of `i`

Comment: I've tried to make more iterations in order to create a larger mass of results (100 buttons, 100 numbers) to have a broader view... If I go and set 98, it will only iterate twice, I'm afraid (numbers2BeDrawn is now 100; it will always crash at (100 - [any value given at i < x])

Comment: That's the working part, I'm afraid: I shuffle all numbers at the beginning, and works that way (See my first part, it's the same). But then I start clicking all buttons in ascending order, 00 to 99, and I need to take those numbers off the draft, hide the button and reshuffle everything. that's the DrawNumbers part that doesn't work.

Comment: Here's where you go wrong. You hide the button with `myButton.Opacity = 0;` and then try to detect if it's hidden by testing the Visibility property. When you set a button opacity to 0, the Visibility value will still be Visible. Instead using opacity, just hide the button with `myButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;`

Comment: Damn right, sir! I 'translated' it wrong from Android, since I needed to keep the space 'occupied' (in Android you've got 3 states, here you have to play with Visibility and Opacity). Thus, I kept code the same as above, but the IF statement now checks for Opacity, not Visibility. I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep it clean and show others, Tomislav's answer got me on the right track.

The error comes from the IF line checking Visibility instead of Opacity. Since I need to keep that space as 'occupied' (not visible but still there, something like Android's INVISIBLE instead of GONE visibility property), I've changed the line and now works perfectly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers2BeDrawn; i++)
        {
            //if (buttonList[i].Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            if (buttonList[i].Opacity > 0)
            {
                int num = rnd.Next(draft.Count());
                myNumber = "" + draft[num];
                if (myNumber.Length < 2) myNumber = "0" + myNumber;
                buttonList[i].Content = myNumber;
                draft.RemoveAt(num);
            }
        }
```

Again, thanks a lot to Mr. Markovski for great support and quick answers.